# Fast Python implementation of the gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, python, gradient-descent

I'm looking for fast Python implémentations of gradient descent optimization algorithm. I have a convex problem , with no constraint, so for now I'm using the BFGS algorithm implemented in scikit-learn ( minimize ).

Is there anything faster / scalable on multi-core systems ?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer

Answer (score 1):

Parallel gradient descent has been implemented [in this repository](https://github.com/angadgill/Parallel-SGD) in Python. It should have a familiar interface, since it's being developed for implementation as a scikit-learn feature.